# flutter using EasyRefresh with Bloc pattern crash

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using eashrefresh to refresh my page. StaggeredGridView was using to show the datas.

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
   crossAxisCount: 1,
   itemCount: _getItemCount(context, state),
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return InkWell(
       child: BMBoomCell(),
       onTap: () {
          _detailTapped(context, index);
        },
       );
     },
     staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
   );
```

Calling the refresh method when clck a button.

```
 _controller.callRefresh();
```

The on onRefresh metheod is below

```
onRefresh: () async {
    _getListDatas(context);
 },

void _getListDatas(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context).add(BMHomeFetchDatas());
 }
```

The bloc is :

```
@override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(
    HomeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is BMHomeFetchDatas) {
      yield BMHomeFetchdingDatas();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5), (){
        LogsUtil().logger.d('加载完成');
      });
      yield BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess();
    }
  }
```

What i want is when get the data, refresh the widget and finishRefresh.

```
// this return the gridview's item count
if (state is BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess) {
      // this code result in error.
      _controller.finishRefresh(success: true);
      return 5;
    }else {
      return 1;
 }
```

And the result is crash, the error is 'widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the progress'.
So how can i using bloc with easyrefresh.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better using init loading data and fetch data together at the same builder.

1. call event for initializing first data
2. state is changed 'BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess'
3. BlocBuilder widget
4. call fetch event for updating data
5. state is changed 'BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess'
6. BlocBuilder update widget

```
@override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(
    HomeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is BMHomeFetchDatas) {
      yield BMHomeFetchdingDatas();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5), (){
        LogsUtil().logger.d('加载完成');
      });
      yield BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess(count: 5);
    } else if (event is BMHomeInitData) {
      yield BMHomeFetchdingDatas();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5), (){
        LogsUtil().logger.d('加载完成');
      });
      yield BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess(count: 1);
    }
  }
```

```
BlocBuilder< HomeBloc, HomeState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is BMHomeFetchDatasSuccess) {
            return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                itemCount: state.count,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return InkWell(
                       child: BMBoomCell(),
                       onTap: () {
                          _detailTapped(context, index);
                        },
                    );
                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
            );
          }
          // Loading Indicator
          return Container();
       }
),
```

Comment: Thanks. I fix it by using BlocConsumer.